# Visual basic accented letters

Tags: string, vb.net, unicode, diacritics

I'm having a little problem when returning an object that has 2 string attributes, as soon as i create it, the string that has accented letters, for some reason transform in wear triangles.

I don't know if is a library, code or configuration problem.

I'm using visual basic .net

In the image you can see the problem.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. It's considered very rude here. Instead, post the text, and then post the errors in a separate block below the code, or via additional comments added to the code section.

Comment: For the question itself... .Net languages use full Unicode encoding by default, and handle diacritics just fine. What you're seeing here is just the debugger. Does the problem show in the application?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. When i run the application the string that returns is: ... aplicaci�n FNA M�vil �gil ...

Comment: I suggest you post the code for the `respCodDes` class.

Comment: It is a problem with the editor that was used to edit this source code.  It is not saving the file with a BOM like VS normally does.  So the compiler does not know that the source file is actually encoded in utf-8.  In VS use File > Save As > click the arrow on the Save button > Save with Encoding > select "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature)".

Comment: Yes, it was a problem with the encoding. I save the file like you said and it was solve. Thank you guys.